# How to display long cell names with large amounts of data in a table

Tags: tables, data-tables, scrolling, data-display, longlist

I am currently working on a web page which has large amounts of data.

The main issue is the **Agents** on the left, have really long strings, and so do the **User Queues** at the top, going across the page. Adding to this, there are 100s of users and queues that will be displayed. I want to try display this page without the use of horizontal scrolling.

I have added a section on the left **Queues: 1-32 of 102**, which will allow the user to click on the next batch of user queues. Maybe, I could do this in interations of 30?

Do you think this could work?

[image]

Comment: What is the reason that your user needs to see all agents and their queue assignments in one view? What is the user trying to accomplish on this screen?

Comment: This is a supervisor view of a digital switchboard for a call centre. They won't need to see everything in one view. Their current table is a long list which scrolls  both horizontally, and vertically. The purpose of this screen is to view what the agents skill level is set to, and what queue they're assigned to. In this case I've set them all to "2". This can range from 0-10, 0 meaning they're not assigned to a queue. In the example, Fiedler Simone, is at skill level 2, and assigned to the queue, CG_UK_Prod_UX_FirstLine_General_Que. The overly long queue name can simply be "Complaints".

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. To further your example, is Fielder Simone a level 2 for all queues, or does their skill set vary depending which queue they're assigned to? Are they assigned to every queue listed above, or a subset of them?

Comment: Fielder Simone doesn't have to be at level 2 for all the queues. The Supervisor can go in, and change their skill level to either 5, or 9, depending on which queue they are assigned to. They will only be assigned to the queues listed in the table 'if' there is a skill level present. If they're set to 0, they're not assigned. There could be potentially 300 queues to the right which would cause scrolling.

Comment: Very good. And - is it important for the supervisor to be able to compare every employee to every other employee? Are employees grouped into teams/squads at all?

Comment: No they won't be comparing, or grouping here at all. It's simply here are a bunch of queues and we need some agents to work them.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question: no, I don't think a massive matrix like this works, even if you only show 30 queues at a time. There's just far too much information on the screen for a manager to take in day-to-day, and far too much visual noise (a user who isn't assigned to a queue does not need to be shown with "0" score.)

Here is what I think you should do, instead.

Write down all of the jobs to be done for this screen. For example:

1. I want to see how many queues are open and in need of an agent.
2. I want to see which agents are available to take on more queues.
3. For each open queue, I want to see the best available agent, based on their score.
4. I want to see how many queues are open for an excessively long time (is it because the agent's score is too low? Do I need to bring in someone else?)

Etc.

Then for each job to be done, you can make a design for that.

*I want to see how many queues are open and in need of an agent.*
You could show the number of open queues and a list of them. The number would help gauge if things are normal, or getting potentially serious. The list would show what's in need of support, and help assess urgency.

*I want to see which agents are available to take on more queues.*
You could show a list of agents who are available, or will soon be available, and the system could suggest 3-5 queues to assign them to next. Better yet, the system could use logic based on the agent's profile and score to automatically assign them to their next queue.

*For each open queue, I want to see the best possible agent, based on their score.* You'd show the empty queues with a list of 3-5 available agents and their corresponding scores, with the option to load more agents.

*I want to see how many queues are open for an excessively long time.* You'd show the queue, the agent, the agent's score, and the length of time it's been open, with any information as to why,

Would you still need a complete list of every queue / agent assignment? Maybe. Some people like having that view to browse, especially if they're looking for something and can't remember exact spellings. Rather than a matrix, you might just want to build a simple table that can be searched on agent name, queue issue details, etc.

My advice is to take a look at gridviews and tabs vs. matrices, based on what your user is trying to do.